# Open ms-access data file (*.mdb) with OpenOffice

Tags: macos, ms-access, openoffice.org

I'm trying to browse an ms-access data base on a mac. Best results so far, I had with using OpenOffice on a Mac like described [here](http://blog.petermolgaard.com/2011/11/22/working-with-access-databases-mdb-files-on-mac-osx/).

Now I can see all the tables. But when I try to access the data with selects, I only see 3 lines of the result set and the contents of string columns is only shown with the first letter.

However, somehow I can access all the data:

- `select count(*) from SomeTable` gives me correct row count.
- `select * from SomeTable where SomeStringCol='SomeWord'` returns the
  expected row(s)(so the select seems to use more than the first
  letter... and `select * from SomeTable where SomeStringCol='S'`
  returns empty result)

Any idea why it is like it is and how to access the full data? (It's not necessary to go with OpenOffice, that was just the best way up to now)

Comment: May be of interest: http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/ from this search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mac+%5Bms-access%5D

Comment: Thank you, but I found the solution.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the solution with the community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally installed [MDB Tool](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/mdb-tool-for-microsoft-access/id513995545?mt=12) which opened the full DB and allowed me csv-exports.

Answer (score 3):

`select * from SomeTable where SomeStringCol='S'` only selects those rows where the only text in SomeStringCol is the letter 'S'. This is probably unlikely (but not impossible)

You would need to change the query to `select * from SomeTable where left(SomeStringCol, 1) ='S'` or `select * from SomeTable where SomeStringCol like 'S*'`

Answer (score 1):

> . when I try to access the data with selects, I only see 3 lines of the result set

As mentioned in the comments to the blog post cited in the question, the unlicensed version of that ODBC driver is crippled and will only return 3 rows.

I recently answered a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/519571/323236) regarding LibreOffice Base on Linux. The solution was to use the (free) [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver to connect LibreOffice to the Access database. The actual steps would be slightly different for Mac OS X, but the basic approach would be the same.